# How to use `$cordovaOauth` to login with google and access google calendar?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-calendar-api, ngcordova

I am trying to get access to google calendar but i get:

```
GET https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList 401 (Unauthorized)
```

The google login works, but no access to the calendar:

```
var scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
]

$cordovaOauth.google(clientId, scopes).then(success, error);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would try going to  [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and enabling [Calendar API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar).

[image]

Comment: Already done that. The calendar permissions don't appear on the login screen.. so i'm assuming the scope doesn't get passed somehow

Comment: I saw that the calendar api generates different OAuth client key than the api key. Are you using that OAuth key?

Comment: I am using the `clientId` generated by the Calendar API, which is to say the app created with OAuth 2.0

Comment: On the login window i should see `Manage your calendars` or something simmilar